# How to save file upload in local folder Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have button upload for uploading PDF in my view, the file was saved in database.

*Here  is my view html:*

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('file', 'File:') !!}
    <p>{!! $attatchment->file !!}</p>
</div>
```

**So I want to save it on my local folder, how to make its works ?**

*I'm using this:* `path="/file_storage";`

Comment: So you're saving the file to the server, saving the path to the database then you want to be able to download it? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: no, i want to save the file in database, also store it into file storage. how to make it works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$file = $request->file('avatar');
            $destinationPath = 'file_storage/';
            $originalFile = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename=strtotime(date('Y-m-d-H:isa')).$originalFile;
            $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
```

it will save the file in public/file_storage

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$file = $request->file('photo');
$time = microtime('.') * 10000; 
$filename = $time.'.'.strtolower( $file->getClientOriginalExtension() );
$destination = 'profile';
$file->move($destination, $filename);
?>
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Please explain your solution.